# Display HTTP Request Information - BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, request, httpconnection

How can I get the all HTTP request headers, method, the suffix of the connection, and all parameters that I added to the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I ran this code on a background thread, which I why I use `UiApplication.invokeLater()` to display results):

```java
   try {
      ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();  // for OS 5.0+
      factory.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[] { 
            TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, 
            TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR 
      });
      // For OS < 5.0
      //HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com;interface=wifi");
      HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) factory.getConnection("http://www.google.com").getConnection();
      conn.setRequestProperty("sessionId", "ABCDEF0123456789");

      final StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();

      String key = "";
      int index = 0;
      // loop over all the header fields, and record their values
      while (key != null) {
         key = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(index);
         if (key != null) {
            String value = conn.getHeaderField(key);
            results.append(key + " = " + value + "\n\n");
         }
         index++;
      }

      results.append("method = " + conn.getRequestMethod() + "\n\n");

      // we (should) know which request properties we've set, so we ask 
      //  for them by name here
      String sessionId = conn.getRequestProperty("sessionId");
      results.append("sessionId = " + sessionId + "\n\n");

      String url = conn.getURL();
      results.append("URL = " + url);

      // show the result on screen (UI thread)
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            textField.setText(results.toString());                                                
         }
      });
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: I should add label field or what ? how to show the request that i send it ?

Comment: @fou, in my example, `textField` is just an instance of [TextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextField.html).  I just used anything that could display the `results` string, which had a listing of the information you asked for.